# “It is the fifth anniversary of his death” vs “This is the fifth anniversary of his death”

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, difference

If I want to mean today is the fifth anniversary of someone’s death, are these two sentences interchangeable?

- “It is the fifth anniversary of his death.”
- “This is the fifth anniversary of his death.”

Answer (score 2):

Yes, they are exactly the same thing in meaning.

The only difference is in grammatical usage as far as talking about a future date. "This" would only be used on that day.  "It is" (or "it's") could be used to talk about the current day or a day in the future, as in "I'm going visit my father's grave on Sunday because it's the fifth anniversary of his death."